# Geometry problem where rectangle ABCD provides area of small rectangles

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

On the rectangle $ABCD$, two points $M$ and $N$ have been marked on the sides $AB$ and $BC$ respectively.

The rectangle has lines drawn between $AN$, $ND$, $MC$, $MD$. It forms many different areas, many of which are triangles.

A triangle is formed in the lower left corner that has points $A$, $M$ and the point where the line $AN$ intersects $MD$ (call that point $E$). That triangle has area $3$.

Another triangle is formed in the upper left corner. It has points $C$, $N$ and the point where the line $ND$ intersects $CM$ (call that point $F$). That triangle has area $2$.

A quadrilateral is formed in the lower right corner. It has points $M$, $B$, $N$ and the point where the line $MC$ intersects $AN$ (call that point $G$). That quadrilateral has an area of ​​$20$.

The goal of the assignment is to find the area of the quadrilateral $DEGF$.

You best understand the assignment when looking at it on paper, so I attached a image down below.

This question is from a high school entrance exam in Sweden.

I have tried to match triangles to each other with no success. I can guess that you would need a giant expression with a bunch of variables which eventually cancel out to get an answer, but I have gotten no success from that path. I also assume that you would need to figure out the length of AB and BC to solve the question. I have also looked at geometric identities but have gotten no success, and found none that seems relevant to the question.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: Here are some hints: (ADN) = (ABCD)/2 = (CDM). You won't be able to find the length of $AB$ and $BC$.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted because of a constructive edit right after @jjagmath 's comment. I have removed some sentences that are not really relevant to the problem at hand here.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

We have $c+x+d=(ABCD)/2$ so $(b+2)+(3+a+20) = (ABCD)/2$ also.
On the other hand, $a+b+x=(ABCD)/2$.

Then $a+b+25 = (ABCD)/2 = a+b+x$, so $x=25$

Answer (score -1):

Using the hint above, $(AMD)+(MBC) = R/2$, where $R$ is the area of the rectangle $ABCD, R=(ABCD)$.
Likewise, $(ABN) + (NCD) = R/2$.
Furthermore, $(AMD) = x +3, (MBC)=t+20+2,$
$(ABN) = 3+z+20, (NCD) = 2 + y,$ where $x$ is $(AED)$, $y$ is $(FDC)$, $z$ is $(AME)$ and $t$ is $(GNF)$.

Then, $(AMD)+(MBC)+ (ABN)+(NCD) = R =x+y+z+t + 52$, and $(DEFG) + x +y+z+t+3+20+2=R.$

Thus, $(DEFG) + R-52 + 27 = R, (DEFG) = 25.$